# How do I SELECT and store multiple rows of a database with the same ID using OLEDB Connection in VisualBasic

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, oledb

```
    Private Sub GetAffectedTraits(ByVal QuestionIndex)
        NumberOfTraitsAffected = 0
        Dim IndexTracker As Integer

        Dim TraitsAffected(23) As String
        'Set all to Null value
        For i As Integer = 1 To 23
            TraitsAffected(i) = " "
        Next

        Dim Command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Affected Trait] FROM Sheet1 WHERE QuestionIndex=" & QuestionIndex & "", TraitValuesConn)
        DB_Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
        While DB_Reader.Read()
            TraitsAffected(IndexTracker) = DB_Reader("Affected Trait")
            IndexTracker += 1
        End While

        For i As Integer = 1 To 23
            MsgBox(TraitsAffected(i)) 'Does not include affected traits yet for some reason
        Next
    End Sub
```

In this code, I'm trying to select and store each 'Affected Trait' from the database stored with the same ID (or QuestionIndex). I want them to be stored separately in the TraitsAffected array. This is what I am currently trying but it does not change the array at all yet. I want to stick with the syntax I have been using with the OLEDB connection.

This is for an academic assignment.

Comment: You just declared `TraitsAffected` on the line before. Why do you think you need to null the values? Anyway `TraitsAffected(i) = " "` is adding a space to each element not a null. Also you ignored index 0. Arrays in .net are zero based. Your array has element  indexes 0 to 23, 24 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not sure of the number of affected traits, it's better to use List instead of Array.

Check the following code and see if it works for you.

```
Private Sub GetAffectedTraits(ByVal QuestionIndex)
    Dim NumberOfTraitsAffected = 0
    Dim TraitsAffected As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    Using TraitValuesConn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("your connection string")
        TraitValuesConn.Open()

        Dim Command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Affected Trait] FROM Sheet1 WHERE QuestionIndex=" & QuestionIndex & "", TraitValuesConn)
        Dim DB_Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
        While DB_Reader.Read()
            TraitsAffected.Add(DB_Reader("Affected Trait"))
        End While
    End Using

    For Each value As String In TraitsAffected
        MsgBox(value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has solved my issue.

Comment: Commands and DataReaders also need to be disposed so, they belong in Using blocks.

Comment: If you find that you need more information to write an answer, ideally it should be ascertained in the comments under the question. However, you can always write an answer and then add comments here under it. It is best to refrain from adding such commentary to the answer though, since that is not part of what should become the long-term record.